# Prometheus AlertManager repeat_interval doesn't work as expected

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

The problem is sending a lot of the same alerts ignoring repeat_interval.

You may see I have configured `repeat_interval: 700h` for `receiver: 'emailhosttracker'` when alertmanager configured `'--data.retention=720h'`
And I expect the repeat interval will be long enough, but I receive a new alert every 4-6 minutes.

Prometheus data:

```sql
host_tracker_down{domain="y-test.yyy", state="down"}1
host_tracker_down{domain="z-test.zzz", state="down"}1
```

Alert rule:

```yaml
  - name: HostTracker
    rules:
      - alert: HostTrackerSiteDown
        expr: host_tracker_down{job="donodeexporter", state="down"} >= 1
        for: 0m
        labels:
          severity: critical
          receiver: emailhosttracker
        annotations:
          summary: "Host Tracker detected site down for last 5 minutes {{ $labels.domain }}"
          description: "Check error code in Cloudflare dashboard for the site {{ $labels.domain }}"
```

My alertmanager config is:

```yaml
---
global:
  resolve_timeout: 1440m
  telegram_api_url: "https://api.telegram.org"
  http_config:
    follow_redirects: true

templates:
  - '/opt/prometheus/etc/rules/alertmanager_notifications_telegram.tmpl'

route:
  group_by: ['instance']
  group_wait: 60s
  group_interval: 5s
  repeat_interval: 719h
  receiver: 'emaildevelopers'

  routes:
  - receiver: 'telegram'
    group_by: [instance, alertname, service]
    group_wait: 10s
    repeat_interval: 24h
    matchers:
    - severity="critical"
  
  - receiver: 'emailootlook'
    group_by: [instance]
    group_wait: 10s
    repeat_interval: 700h
    matchers:
    - receiver="email"
  
  - receiver: 'emailhosttracker'
    group_by: [domain, alertname]
    group_wait: 30s
    repeat_interval: 700h
    matchers:
    - receiver="emailhosttracker"

  - receiver: 'blackhole'
    group_wait: 90s
    repeat_interval: 700h
    matchers:
    - severity=~"warning|info"
  
inhibit_rules:
- equal: ['instance']
  source_matchers:
    - severity = critical
  target_matchers:
    - "severity =~ warning|info"

receivers:
  - name: 'telegram'
    telegram_configs:
    - api_url: 'https://api.telegram.org'
      bot_token: 'TecsJU'
      chat_id: -61
      disable_notifications: false
      http_config:
        follow_redirects: true
      send_resolved: true
      parse_mode: HTML
      message: '{{ template "telegram.default.message" . }}'

  - name: 'emailootlook'
    email_configs:
    - to: '69@tasks.teamwork.com'
      from: 'M L <devops@digi.com>'
      smarthost: 'smtp.sendgrid.net:587'
      hello: 'digi.com'
      auth_username: 'apikey'
      auth_password: 'SG.5drTHRs'
      send_resolved: false
      headers:
        Subject: " Alert !! on {{ range .Alerts }}{{ .Labels.alertname | safeHtml }} - {{ .Labels.instance | safeHtml }} {{ end }}"
      html: |
        {{ range .Alerts }}
        <pre>---</pre>
        <p>{{ .Labels.alertname | safeHtml }} on **{{  .Labels.instance | safeHtml }}**</p>
        <p>Labels:</br>
        - {{ .Labels.alertname | safeHtml }}</br>
        - **{{ .Labels.instance | safeHtml }}**</p>
        <p>Annotations:</br>
        *{{ .Annotations.description | safeHtml }}*</br>
        <p>
        {{ end }}

  - name: 'emailhosttracker'
    email_configs:
    - to: .....
  
  - name: 'blackhole'
```